# Multi Class image classification in android apps

Tags: android, firebase, tensorflow-lite

Is it possible to build an android app that is able to classify images with multiple classes? As of now, I see that there is only one label classification because the folders and images of the image dataset have to be arranged such that  it is suitable for only one label. For example, if I want to classify whether a given image is a vegetable or fruit, and also what type of vegetable or fruit, that would be multi label classification.

Comment: what do you mean label? Give example using flow in the app

Comment: @BorisRuzanov Lets take an example of a classifier which deals with cars and trucks. The model is able to predict whether a vechicle is a car or a truck and also what type of car or truck. So the model would not only predict car, but it would say car and sedan.

Comment: Have added code. Please let me know if it helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand you right. If so just use needed model with needed fields for example Car with fields type (for truck or sedan) and model (for toyota or bmw) and when receive data somehow extract that information and check what data it as inside. Please check code below

Model class

```
public class Test {
    // Set sedan or truck
    String type;
    // Set BMW or Toyota
    String model;

    public Test(String type, String model) {
        this.type = type;
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }
}
```

Checking

```
if(input.equals(car.getModel())){
    //Doing something if you found needed model
    //Showing needed image
}else {
    //Doing something if model was not found
}
```

In case of tensor flow:
To  make it work with tensor flow you are separating this flow on two parts. First you need to train your model ON SIDE OF TENSOR FLOW with images fruits / cars whatever you want and as much as you want to get accuracy which you want. When this part is ready with help of android you are making "request" with photo to tensorFlow and extract the response and inflate it in model above and after that make a check and show needed result which I also showed in code above.

Comment: This makes sense, but how would I use this in something like tensorflowlite?

Comment: @NoLand'sMan i have added some details about tensor flow part